# Getting the Spawn EACCES error in Ubuntu - node environment

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-usemin, grunt-build-control

Getting the Spawn EACCES error in Ubuntu -  node environment

```
Running "imagemin:dist" (imagemin) task
✔ public/img/github.png (saved 183 B - 2%)
✔ public/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png (already optimized)
✔ public/img/facebook.png (saved 96 B - 1%)
Warning: spawn EACCES Use --force to continue.
```

Comment: Same error for me, it was working in Windows 10 and copied the code to Ubuntu. You got any fix?

Answer (score -3):

Check that the files you are working with have permissions granted for your account.

Comment: I have given all the permissions and tried. It some how fails to minify jpg files , it works fine if all the images are of png.

Answer (score -3):

It is a permission error. Try using sudo... `sudo grunt imagemin`.